# Iodobenzene reaction with copper(I) ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Does it reduce it to benzene like $\ce{LiAlH4}$ does? Any source for this reaction?

Comment: https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/ullmann-reaction.shtm

Comment: I saw that but it says copper solid not positive ion unless I’m not seeing it can you tell me the section ?

Comment: Under the "Mechanism of the Ullmann Reaction" section, The active species is a copper(I)-compound which undergoes oxidative addition with the second equivalent of halide, followed by reductive elimination and the formation of the aryl-aryl carbon bond. Also, there must be some Cu present

Comment: You need a nucleophile to replace iodide here. For example: $$\ce{Ar-Br + CuCN ->[solvent][\Delta, \gt \pu{125 ^\circ C}] Ar-CN}$$ I have done this with 60% yield.

Comment: For a room temperature Ullmann reaction, see: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00522a058